# Link Custom Payload Buttons to Intents

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am Already using this custom payload to generate buttons but how can I link specific intent to the buttons like in the example below if user clicks yes **follow up default intent yes** response and so on.

[image: Dialog Flow Screen Shot]

```
{
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "text": "Yes",
        "link": "https://example.com",
        "type": "button",
        "icon": {
          "color": "#FF9800",
          "type": "chevron_right"
        },
        "event": {
          "languageCode": "en",
          "name": "DefaultWelcomeIntent.DefaultWelcomeIntent-yes",
          "parameters": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "event": {
          "parameters": {},
          "name": "DefaultWelcomeIntent.DefaultWelcomeIntent-no",
          "languageCode": "en"
        },
        "type": "button",
        "link": "https://example.com",
        "text": "No",
        "icon": {
          "type": "chevron_right",
          "color": "#FF9800"
        }
      }
    ]

  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [Suggestion Chip Response Type](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger#suggestion_chip_response_type) approach in your custom payload in which you will be able to have your desired "Yes" and "No" button. Once you click on your desired button, it will return as a **text** **response** on the Dialogflow Messenger and you will be redirected to your follow-up intent that matches the text response based on the training phrases  of the follow-up intent (eg. "Yes", "No", etc).

You may try below sample custom payload and must be able to redirect you to either `follow-up intent - yes` or  `follow-up intent - no` depending on the button you click.

```
{
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "type": "chips",
        "options": [
          {
            "text": "Yes"
          },
          {
            "text": "No"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

**UPDATE:**
There is another approach for your use case that uses your current custom payload script. Please see below updated custom payload script.

```
{
    "richContent": [
        [{
                "event": {
                    "languageCode": "en",
                    "parameters": {},
                    "name": "click_yes"
                },
                "text": "Yes",
                "link": "",
                "icon": {
                    "type": "chevron_right",
                    "color": "#FF9800"
                },
                "type": "button"
            },
            {
                "text": "No",
                "event": {
                    "parameters": {},
                    "name": "click_no",
                    "languageCode": "en"
                },
                "link": "",
                "icon": {
                    "color": "#FF9800",
                    "type": "chevron_right"
                },
                "type": "button"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

As you can see, I changed the value of the event name for both buttons. `click_yes` for button **Yes** and `click_no` for button **No**.

Next step is to go to your **Default Welcome Intent - yes** and under **Events**, input `click_yes`. By doing this, the intent will be triggered by the `click_yes` event that is tied up to your **Yes** button. (Do the same step for **Default Welcome Intent - no** by using the event name `click_no`.)

Answer (score 0):

1. create intent1
2. you need to fill the event section name with "intent2" and languge code "eng" vs.
3. create a intent named intent2
4. write "intent2" in the intent2's event section

now when your button triggered intent2 event your flow will continue on the intent2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).